# Fragment view not filling the whole fragment space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a Fragment composed of three subfragments :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/header"
        class="xxx.xxx.xxx.HeaderFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/content"
        class="xxx.xxx.xxx.ContentFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/footer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        class="xxx.xxx.xxx.FooterFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This way, the ContentFragment fills the space between HeaderFragment and FooterFragment, as shown in the picture below :

green = header

blue = content

red = footer

[image]

Now I would like to add two views to the ContentFragment layout (one TextView and one ScrollView), so that those views take the whole blue space available.

Here is the layout for ContentFragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightBlue">

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/veryLongTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what I get instead :

[image]

Can someone explain why there is some space between the bottom of the scrollview and the bottom of the blue part ? It is not what I have defined in the constraints, which is rendered like this in Android Studio :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure why this is happening. My guess is that Android cannot compute the right height for the ContentFragment at runtime, because the problem disappears if I define the fragments height using [Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline.html) as shown below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/header"
            class="xxx.xxx.xxx.HeaderFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/topLimit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/content"
            class="xxx.xxx.xxx.ContentFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomLimit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topLimit" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            class="xxx.xxx.xxx.FooterFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottomLimit"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/topLimit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/bottomLimit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which is rendered like this :

[image]